# Define source of a click?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to define the source of a click? I can access my MainActivity through either clicking on a RecyclerView or through a Notification action. Depending on which it is, I need to provide different info. Is there a way of saying: if click is from recyclerview then..., else if it is from notification action then...?

What I can think of so far is this, but the problem is I am not using buttons as such:

```
Button mClickButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton1);
mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
Button mClickButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.clickButton2);
mClickButton2.setOnClickListener(this);

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case  R.id.clickButton1: {
            // do something for button 1 click
            break;
        }

        case R.id.clickButton2: {
            // do something for button 2 click
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: All View objects have `setOnClickListener`, not just `Button`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to define two different calling intents for the same activity and put info for each View Example :

```
  mClickButton1.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent view1_int = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
      view1_int.putExtra("Calling Intent" ,"RecyclerView");
      startaActivityForResult(view1_int);


}
});
mClickButton2.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener(){
   public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent view2_int = new Intent (this, MainActivity.class);
      view1_int.putExtra("Calling Intent" ,"Notification action");
      startaActivityForResult(view1_int);


}
});
```

and in the onCreate Method in your MainActivity you can say :

```
 String callin_view;
 callin_view =getresources.getIntent.getExtras("Calling_Intent");
```

This will retrieve the name of the calling source you defined

Comment: You only need one `View.OnClickListener`